# Error amplifier in dc dc converter chip

Tags: dc-dc-converter, flyback

I am trying to design a dc-dc converter using the UC3844 IC. The working is clear to me. But the datasheet has an application circuit that is a bit confusing for me. The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3844.pdf).

The circuit in question is the one shown below -

[image: circuit].

Pin2 is the error amplifier and should be connected to the Vout. How is this connected in this application circuit ? Which secondary should it be connected precisely ?

Comment: The UC384x series is an old design and has been cloned by other vendors as well (ONSemi for example) since it became available. Also, there are slightly improved versions (UC384xA, UC384xB). There are many extended data sheet versions, and many Application Notes as well to this family. You should familiarize yourself with the available technical literature. This example is a no-feedback version, where the output Voltage is not regulated. If you want regulation, you should choose a feedback version.

Comment: What I can do is use an optocoupler on the output and feed it back to pin 2, right ?

Comment: In general: yes, but I still say: read the documentation, there are plenty of such examples.

Comment: Also, if I have more than 1 secondary, which will be the feedback from ?

Comment: That's a classic flyback knowledge: if the secondary windings are sufficiently closely wound, the secondary voltages will be "in sync" (as dictated by the ratio of the turns), so it's enough to feed back only one of them (preferably the one which has the most stringent tolerance). Or you could make a weighted feedback signal from multiple outputs.

Comment: @LaszloValko. Then the design that they have is valid as it is a tap from the auxilliary which is also a type of secondary, right ?

Comment: Basically no, because the bias winding has to be fully isolated from the secondaries, therefore they cannot be sufficiently closely wound. Of course, there will be _some_ correlation between them.

Comment: Question is, is the correlation enough, can you get transformer output voltages that meet your specification ? If you want super accurate voltages independent of load: my answer would be no. If you just need voltages with +/- 10 % accuracy to run circuits on, I would say: Yes.  As often in electronics: it does not have to be accurate, as long as it is close enough (even better: within specification).

Answer (score 1):

The error amp is connected to the secondary labeled "NC" in this diagram. From there the signal gets rectified (by D3 and D2) and filtered (That chunk of Rs and Cs) before going through a voltage divider (R3 and R4) to pin 2. R2 probably provides some sort of DC bias to the feedback signal, probably to prevent it from destabilizing during start up or heavy load transients.

As a side note: That datasheet is oddly incomplete for TI. Usually there is much more information about the application and the per-pin requirements and recommendations. Possibly there is an App note you could look at for this part that could explain some of the choices they made in this circuit.

Comment: Regarding R2: it is a resistor needed for supplying power to the IC during startup. Then the transformer is not delivering any power yet (switching has not started yet) so R2 has to supply the power. As soon as Q1 is switching, the transformer provides power via D3, this voltage is then used as supply for the IC and as a feedback signal via R3 and R4 to the feedback input on pin 2.